# Is it proper to have consecutive adverbs?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it proper grammar to have consecutive adverbs in a sentence?

e.g. *"It was not exactly accidentally...*.

My thought is that is probably is not proper, especially in this case. The above could have been rewritten, *"It was not exactly accidental..."*.

Comment: Not a grammatical problem, certainly not a matter of "proper grammar", which doesn't exist, I'm afraid. It's more that it doesn't **sound** right to get two adverbs together, especially if they're derived with _-ly_. The intonation is awkward.

Comment: This question needs rephrasing, because as it stands it can only be rhetorical. *Obviously* adverbs can modify other adverbs — That plane is moving *very slowly*, this snail is moving *incredibly fast* — and look, even the [Wikipedia article on adverbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb) mentions that right in its second sentence: "Adverbs can modify verbs, adjectives (including numbers), clauses, sentences, and other adverbs".

Comment: Ah I see your point and agree completely (in fact now I feel silly asking it in that way). Perhaps I should word with more of a tone such as @JohnLawler suggested—does it *sound* right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are plenty of circumstances in which consecutive adverbs occur.

Using the adverb combination of OP's example, one could form a sentence like *Though Sarah's pregnancy came as a surprise to many, it was not exactly accidentally achieved.*

Other more common double-adverb constructions include phrases in which an adverb like *very* or *rather* precedes another adverb.

Answer (score 4):

It is fine to write for example

> It was not exactly accidentally done.

This means it is not exactly true that it was accidentally done.

Comment: I'd instinctively switch *accidentally* and *done* around in that sentence to avoid the double-adverb awkwardness.

Answer (score 2):

As John suggests, ‘proper grammar’ is a chimera. We can draw conclusions about language only on the evidence of what actually occurs in it, and consecutive adverbs certainly do occur. The *locus classicus* could well be (my emphasis):

> I'll be your dream I'll be your wish I'll be your fantasy.
>
> I'll be your hope I'll be your love be everything that you need.
>
> I'll love you more with every breath **truly madly deeply**.

Comment: I don't think *truly madly deeply* there qualifies as three consecutive adverbs in the sense OP is talking about. It's just repetition/conflation, as is common in poetry/lyrics - if there *is* such a thing as "grammar", you can't really say that's a "grammatical" usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I know. I just wanted to quote it.

Comment: It is a nice sequence of adverbs, I must admit. You've already sucked me in far enough that I now know it's both a film and a song. I shall hold you to account if I end up watching/hearing both, and either/both disappoint! :)

Comment: Commas and 'and' between them would make it a better sentence, wouldn't it?